# How to declare a type as nullable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, nullable

I have an interface in TypeScript.

```
interface Employee{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    salary: number;
}
```

I would like to make `salary` as a nullable field (Like we can do in C#). Is this possible to do in TypeScript?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

All fields in JavaScript (and in TypeScript) can have the value `null` or `undefined`.

You can make the field *optional* which is different from nullable.

```
interface Employee1 {
    name: string;
    salary: number;
}

var a: Employee1 = { name: 'Bob', salary: 40000 }; // OK
var b: Employee1 = { name: 'Bob' }; // Not OK, you must have 'salary'
var c: Employee1 = { name: 'Bob', salary: undefined }; // OK
var d: Employee1 = { name: null, salary: undefined }; // OK

// OK
class SomeEmployeeA implements Employee1 {
    public name = 'Bob';
    public salary = 40000;
}

// Not OK: Must have 'salary'
class SomeEmployeeB implements Employee1 {
    public name: string;
}
```

Compare with:

```
interface Employee2 {
    name: string;
    salary?: number;
}

var a: Employee2 = { name: 'Bob', salary: 40000 }; // OK
var b: Employee2 = { name: 'Bob' }; // OK
var c: Employee2 = { name: 'Bob', salary: undefined }; // OK
var d: Employee2 = { name: null, salary: 'bob' }; // Not OK, salary must be a number

// OK, but doesn't make too much sense
class SomeEmployeeA implements Employee2 {
    public name = 'Bob';
}
```

Comment: Looks like [strictly nullable types and strict null-checks](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7140) have been implemented and will arrive with Typescript 2.0! (or `typescript@next` now.)

Comment: are you sure about var c in the first example?  It seems to me that var b and var c are the same there.

Comment: In order to set null or undefined value without compilation error, the tsconfig "strict" option must be removed or equals to "false" `"strict" : false`

Comment: This is incorrect. JS distinguish between null and undefined.
Correct code should be `salary:number|null;`
If you do `salary?:number; salary = null;` You will get an error. However, `salary = undefined;` will work just fine in this case.
Solution: use Union i.e. '|'

Comment: (Downvoting as it is now obsolete / not good practice.)

Comment: Huh why not `| null`. You say yourself that undefined isn't the same as null. Optional is undefined, so this doesn't the answer at all?

Comment: I think this is not the answer to the question. We are not talking about Javascript. Besides null <> undefined

Comment: @mindplay.dk it does not seem to be default behaviour in typescript 4.9

Comment: Properties don't allow `null` if [`"strictNullChecks": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/strictNullChecks.html) is set (e.g. in the `tsConfig.json`).

Answer (score 341):

To be more **C#** like, define the `Nullable` type like this:

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null;

interface Employee{
   id: number;
   name: string;
   salary: Nullable<number>;
}
```

**Bonus:**

To make `Nullable` behave like a built in Typescript type, define it in a `global.d.ts` definition file in the root source folder. This path worked for me: `/src/global.d.ts`

Comment: Using this breaks the auto-completion of object properties. For example if we have `emp: Partial<Employee>`, we can do `emp.id` or `emp.name` etc but if we have `emp: Nullable<Employee>`, we can't do `emp.id`

Comment: @YousufKhan That is true. That's probably because since `emp` is potentially nullable, the `id` property might be invalid. To make the code robust, you should probably use an `if` block to check for null first, like this: `if (emp) { console.log(emp.id); }` If you use such an `if`-block, the TypeScript compiler and the editor "see" that the object inside the block is not null and thus will not generate errors and allow auto completion inside the if-block. (It works well in my Visual Studio 2019 editor and I assume it will work in Visual Studio Code too. But I don't know about other editors.)

Comment: @YousufKhan . . . When using `emp: Partial<Employee>`, the resulting type contains all properties from `Employee`, but those properties will be nullable. (Well, `undefined`able might be the more appropriate term here.) So all properties of `emp` are available, but nullable. When using `emp: Nullable<Employee>`, the `emp` variable itself is nullable. If it is not null, it should be a valid full `Employee` instance. You could combine those as well: `emp: Nullable<Partial<Employee>>`. In that case, `emp` is nullable itself, but when not null, its properties can all be nullable as well.

Comment: Could you add Value and HasValue too like Nullable in C#? A generic class could probably be used but you will have to instantiate it too instead of just using a type declaration.

Comment: Maybe even `type _Nullable<T> = T | null | undefined;`? That's the vuefire definition

Answer (score 261):

Union type is in my mind best option in this case:

```
interface Employee{
   id: number;
   name: string;
   salary: number | null;
}

// Both cases are valid
let employe1: Employee = { id: 1, name: 'John', salary: 100 };
let employe2: Employee = { id: 1, name: 'John', salary: null };
```

EDIT : For this to work as expected, you should enable the `strictNullChecks` in `tsconfig`.

Comment: If you use --strictNullChecks (which you should), this is a valid solution. I would not use it in favour of optional members, since it forces you to add an explicit null on all literal objects, but for function return values, it is the way to go.

Comment: To clarify @geon's suggestion: an `optional property` of an interface is declared with a `?` *on the property name*.  `salary?: number` means that `salary` can be omitted, or equivalently given value `undefined`, but cannot give it value `null`. [Good demonstration of different declarations using optional and/or null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57243788/199364).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes. Using `salary: number | null` or `salary: number | undefined` is still great, because it forces you do set it to something, even if that something is `undefined`. It is easy to forget otherwise.

Answer (score 72):

Just add a question mark `?` to the optional field.

```
interface Employee{
   id: number;
   name: string;
   salary?: number;
}
```

Comment: As Ryan pointed out... ? means optional in typescript, not nullable.

Without ? means the var must be set to a value including null or undefined.
With ? you can skip the whole declaration-thingy.

Comment: Thank you! I googled for "typescript optional value" so this is **exactly** what I was looking for.

Comment: As per @HeNrik's comment: This is an answer to a slightly different question than was asked. Since 2.0 in 2016, [Here is a good demonstration of all possible combinations of optional / undefined / null when declaring a type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57243788/199364).

Answer (score 42):

You can just implement a user-defined type like the following:

```
type Nullable<T> = T | undefined | null;

var foo: Nullable<number> = 10; // ok
var bar: Nullable<number> = true; // type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<number>'
var baz: Nullable<number> = null; // ok

var arr1: Nullable<Array<number>> = [1,2]; // ok
var obj: Nullable<Object> = {}; // ok

 // Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. 
 // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
var arr2: Nullable<Array<string>> = [1,2];
```

Comment: This is dope, and imho should be part of TypeScript as a default!

Answer (score 29):

```
type MyProps = {
  workoutType: string | null;
};
```

Answer (score 21):

```
type Nullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null;
};
```

and then u can use it

```
Nullable<Employee>
```

This way you can still use `Employee` interface as it is somewhere else

Answer (score 9):

```
type WithNullableFields<T, Fields> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends Fields 
    ? T[K] | null | undefined
    : T[K]
}

let employeeWithNullableSalary: WithNullableFields<Employee, "salary"> = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  salary: null
}
```

Or you can turn off strictNullChecks ;)

And the reversed version:

```
type WithNonNullableFields<T, Fields> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends Fields
    ? NonNullable<T[K]>
    : T[K]
}
```

Comment: This is very useful and very undervoted answer.

Comment: Basically, this helper type allows to make specific "fields" as nullable. It gives flexibility if not all fields should become nullable.

Answer (score 8):

Nullable type can invoke runtime error.
So I think it's good to use a compiler option `--strictNullChecks` and declare `number | null` as type. also in case of nested function, although input type is null, compiler can not know what it could break, so I recommend use `!`(exclamination mark).

```
function broken(name: string | null): string {
  function postfix(epithet: string) {
    return name.charAt(0) + '.  the ' + epithet; // error, 'name' is possibly null
  }
  name = name || "Bob";
  return postfix("great");
}

function fixed(name: string | null): string {
  function postfix(epithet: string) {
    return name!.charAt(0) + '.  the ' + epithet; // ok
  }
  name = name || "Bob";
  return postfix("great");
}
```

Reference.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions

Comment: Two comments: **a)** Modern JS or TS can use the "null-coalesce" operator `??`. This is less likely to result in accidental errors than the "falsey" logical-OR operator `||`. `name = name ?? "Bob";` is cleaner way to replace `null` with a default value.  **b)** I would not use `!` in this code. Any time you use `!`, you make it possible that a future maintainer of code might make a mistake, resulting in a rare runtime error: painful to debug. Safer is `const name2:string = name ?? "Bob";` `function postfix(...) { return name2.charAt(0) ...`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by editing the tsconfig.json file.

Under: `"strict": true`,
add those 2 lines:

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
"strictNullChecks": false,
```

Comment: does this not defeat the purpose of typescript? surely there has to by a way to set an object property or object to some null safe state?

Comment: @d0rf47, I haven't tested it but I think you can use the NonNullable helper for that use case https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype

Comment: I think this defeats the purpose of everything, haha, just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

i had this same question a while back.. all types in ts are nullable, because void is a subtype of all types (unlike, for example, scala).

see if this flowchart helps - https://github.com/bcherny/language-types-comparison#typescript

Comment: -1: This is not true at all. As for `void` being 'subtype of all types' ([bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type)), refer to [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3076). Also the chart you provided for scala is incorrect as well. `Nothing` in scala is, in fact, the bottom type. Typescript, atm, **does not** have bottom type while scala **does**.

Comment: "Subtype of all types" != bottom type. See the TS spec here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#327-the-undefined-type

Answer (score 1):

Basing on previous answers, I'd like to add one more solution and explain it.

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null; 

type SetAllNullable<T, ExceptKeys = void> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends ExceptKeys
        ? T[P]
        : Nullable<T[P]>
};
```

For example we have type `Person`

```
type Person = {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  location: string;
}
```

and we want to set all fields to `nullable` except `name`. We can do it this way:

```
type PersonBrief = SetAllNullable<Person, 'name'>
```

As a result we'll have a new type where all fields except `name` can have `null` as value.

We can also provide a list of fields to be excluded from setting it to `nullable`. The simple ways is

```
type PersonBriefOne = SetAllNullable<Person, 'name' | 'age'>;
```

and a bit more complex is

```
// `as const` makes this constant read-only and safe for making a type
const excludeFiledsList = ['name', 'age'] as const;

// this tricky string takes all array values by index and creates union type
type ExludedFieldsType = typeof excludeFiledsList[number];

type PersonBriefTwo = SetAllNullable<Person, ExludedFieldsType>;
```

So types `PersonBriefOne` and `PersonBriefTwo` will be similar.

One more note is that `ExceptKeys` value is optional and can be skipped - in this case all fields will be set to `nullable`, and even if non-existing key(s) will be provided as second argument, it will not cause any error and all fields will be set to `nullable` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can define property as `Partial` and `Nullable` with type:

```
export type PartialNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | null;
};
```

Them just use

```
interface Employee {
  id: number;
  company_id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const EmployeeData: PartialNullable<Employee> = {
    age: null,
    name: null
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `Nullable` like `type` like the following:

```
type NullOrUndefinedOr<T> = T extends void ? never : null | undefined | T;
```

This is an example of how it would look:

```
/* "fictitious" src/services/product.ts */

import { Product } from "@/models/product";
import { ProductRepository } from "@/repositories/product";
import { Logger } from "@/telemetry";

const log = Logger.create(__filename);

export async function getProductById(id: int): Promise<NullOrUndefinedOr<Product>> {
  try{
    const repo = await ProductRepository.create(process.env.DB_CONN_STRING);
    return await repo.findOne({ productId: id });
  }catch(err){
    log.exception(err);
    return null;
  }
}
```

> **Note**: You can also add this type to your `src/types/global.d.ts` to used it anywhere in your project without having to import it.

```
/* global.d.ts */

declare global {
  type NullOrUndefinedOr<T> = T extends void ? never : null | undefined | T;
  
  /** define all global types you need **/
}

/**
if you don't import or export anything else in this file
ensure to export at least an empty object to avoid the
compiler skipping this file
**/
export {};
```