# Typescript 'optional' (nullable) '?' syntax not working (partially)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, intellisense

I'd like to declare a number on a class as optional, using the '?' operator.

```
export class DummyClass {
    dummyId?: number;   
}
```

Visual Studio doesn't let me compile because of a  `'; is expected. Unexpected token'` error. However when I e.g. declare a function or interface, it works without problems:

```
void(sup?: number) {} // nothing to complain here
```

Are there some rules about this? Or is something wrong with Intellisense?

Comment: TypeScript does not have a concept of 'nullable'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220114/how-to-declare-a-type-as-nullable-in-typescript

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require that property to be set, you can just have:

```
export class DummyClass {
    dummyId: number;   
}
```

In this example, `dummyId` is undefined until someone sets a value. Essentially, properties need no special character to say "you don't have to set me".

When you accept an argument, you can make it optional. This is true of methods and constructors:

```
export class DummyClass {
    constructor(public dummyId?: number) {

    }


    doSomething(dummyId?: number) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's also true for interfaces.