# error TS2345: Argument of type 'Menu' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, typescript

Good day. I'm new to Type Script, using VSCode.

Getting following **errors**:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Menu' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ state: string; name: string; type: string; icon: string;
 badge?: undefined; children?: undefine...'
```

the **code**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface BadgeItem {
  type: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface ChildrenItems {
  state: string;
  name: string;
  type?: string;
}

export interface Menu {
  state: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  icon: string;
  badge?: BadgeItem[];
  children?: ChildrenItems[];
}

const MENUITEMS = [
  {
    state: '/',
    name: 'HOME',
    type: 'link',
    icon: 'explore'
  },
  {
    state: 'account',
    name: 'ACCOUNT',
    type: 'sub',
    icon: 'explore',
    badge: [
      {type: 'purple', value: 'new'}
    ],
    children: [
        {state: 'users', name: 'USERS'},
    ]
  }
];

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  getAll(): Menu[] {
    return MENUITEMS;
  }

  add(menu: Menu) {
    MENUITEMS.push(menu);
  }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: set first item of `MENUITEMS` to `{
    state: '/',
    name: 'HOME',
    type: 'link',
    icon: 'explore', badge: [], children: []
  }`

Comment: I have changed the code but still get the same error.

Comment: The correct way to fix this is to give your `MENUITEMS` an appropriate type to help the TypeScript compiler out. `const MENUITEMS: Menu[] = [...]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220114/how-to-declare-a-type-as-nullable-in-typescript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just specify the type of `MENUITEMS` like below, the warning will go away

```
const MENUITEMS : Menu[] = [
  {
    state: '/',
    name: 'HOME',
    type: 'link',
    icon: 'explore'
  },
  {
    state: 'account',
    name: 'ACCOUNT',
    type: 'sub',
    icon: 'explore',
    badge: [
      {type: 'purple', value: 'new'}
    ],
    children: [
        {state: 'users', name: 'USERS'},
    ]
  }
];
```