# Can an optional parameter be null in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, undefined, option-type, nullable

According to [this article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/non-nullable-types-in-typescript), when strict null checking is enabled in TypeScript, you cannot assign `null` or `undefined` to a variable unless it is explicitly allowed with a union.

```js
// required value
let req: string;
req = "Something";  // OK
req = null;      // Error
req = undefined; // Error

// nullable value
let nbl: string | null;
nbl = "Something";  // OK
nbl = null;      // OK
nbl = undefined; // Error
```

But is `null` allowed in an *optional* value in TypeScript?

```js
// optional value
let opt?: string; // (actually invalid, as optional types cannot be used for variable declarations, but that's not the point, so imagine we are dealing with function parameters or something)
opt = "Something"; // OK
opt = null; // OK? Error?
opt = undefined; // OK
```

Or is

```js
opt?: string;
```

equivalent to

```js
opt: string | undefined;
```

thus not allowing `null` just like recommended by [Microsoft's Coding guidelines](http://let%20name:%20string;%20name%20=%20%22Marius%22;%20%20//%20OK%20name%20=%20null;%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Error%20name%20=%20undefined;%20//%20Error)?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

EDIT: **Important Note** As Quentin C pointed out in the below comment, the behavior listed here is only when strict null checking is enabled: `"strictNullChecks": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

---

The types `null` and `undefined` are handled as separate types. The *optional* type is special, also allowing arguments to be left out of function calls.

**1. Without a union or optional, nothing except the type itself is allowed.**

```js
function foo(bar: string) {
    console.info(bar);
}

foo("Hello World!"); // OK
foo(null); // Error
foo(undefined); // Error
foo() // Error
```

**2. To additionally allow `null`, a union with `null` can be made.**

```js
function foo(bar: string | null) {
    console.info(bar);
}

foo("Hello World!"); // OK
foo(null); // OK
foo(undefined); // Error
foo() // Error
```

**3. Allowing `undefined` works similarly. Note that the argument cannot be left out or `null`.**

```
function foo(bar: string | undefined) {
    console.info(bar);
}

foo("Hello World!"); // OK
foo(null); // Error
foo(undefined); // OK
foo() // Error
```

**4. You can also allow both, but the argument MUST still be given.**

```js
function foo(bar: string | null | undefined) {
    console.info(bar);
}

foo("Hello World!"); // OK
foo(null); // OK
foo(undefined); // OK
foo() // Error
```

**5. With *optional* you can leave the argument out, or pass `undefined`, BUT NOT `null`.**

```js
function foo(bar?: string) {
    console.info(bar);
}

foo("Hello World!"); // OK
foo(null); // Error
foo(undefined); // OK
foo() // OK
```

**6. To allow all three special cases, *optional* and `null` can be combined.**

```js
function foo(bar?: string | null) {
    console.info(bar);
}

foo("Hello World!"); // OK
foo(null); // OK
foo(undefined); // OK
foo() // OK
```

---

Also, *optional* is only usable in parameter or other type declarations, such as interfaces, not on regular variables. As it would make no sense to *leave out* the value of a variable when assigning to it.

Thus,

```js
let d?: string;
```

would make no sense and results in a compilation error.

Comment: For people like me that don't read properly the question, the behavior listed here is only when strict null checking is enabled. "strictNullChecks": true in tsconfig.json

Comment: FYI, `undefined` isn't allowed in example #5 doesn't when `"exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true` is specified in `tsconfig.js`.

Comment: `let d?: string;` is *not* an assignment, it's a declaration. The keyword `let` makes this admittedly confusing. It does make sense to have declarations without assignment and that's why JS and many languages allow it, even for optionals/nullables/etc.

Answer (score -3):

`let d?: string;` declares the type as `string | undefined`.

This is because `undefined` is the default value for JS variables.

Comment: You are not right, `let d?: string` is not valid in TypeScript. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13321