# Typescript: use type declaration to force a null-check?

Tags: typescript

I know that you can declare a [type as nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220114/how-to-declare-a-type-as-nullable-in-typescript) in typescript

But this doesn't force the user to do a null check, e.g.

```js
function maybeReturnString(): string | null { ... }
function getOnlyString(str: string) { ... }

const maybeString = maybeReturnString();
getOnlyString(maybeString) // OK
```

What's the proper way to make the build fail in case I don't check for null?

Is there something similar to `Option[String]` in Scala or `String?` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of TypeScript you're running but that should definitely throw a compile time error, as demonstrated in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYE8BGBTAStqEAJzAGUoiYwBzACgEoAuRAZwqusQB9EwQAbfogDeAKACQMYIloBZVFAAWAOiKowAEzjIGiAHwBeRAAZlAVnoiJ4ogWJIARAE04IRAHcEAQgcBuCQC+ohK2hCS8Avz+QaKgkLAIiNQEAPJg-OjklDS0AG6o-CDYzGzZ1EyIuXAwGlbiEAgscPzYyvxwdA4AKooKHnBEANbYGj4ANJUFRfTRwQ1gbCgYOIhGaFh4diRZHAz+yVBpGTs56zgzwUA) (using your own code).

To answer your other question, you can also use the `string?` syntax which is equivalent to `string | undefined`.

Comment: Weird, checking

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I didn't set the config `strictNullChecks=true`