# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

actually, I want to show the recorded Date on my page.for that, I have created a function for showing my recorded Date.but I am stuck when I found an unexpected error.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BookService } from 'src/app/services/book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-book',
  templateUrl: './update-book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-book.component.css']
})
export class UpdateBookComponent implements OnInit {

  updateBookForm:FormGroup
  book:any
  constructor(private service:BookService,private route : ActivatedRoute,private   router:Router,private fb:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getBookById(this.route.snapshot.params.id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.book=data;

      this.updateBookForm = this.fb.group({
        id:[data.id],
        title:[data.title, Validators.required],
        author:[data.author, Validators.required],
        description:[data.description, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(30)])],
        rate:[data.rate],
        dateStart:[this.formatDate (data.dateStart)],
        dateRead:[data.dateRead],
      })
    })
  }

  formatDate(date: Date){
    if(date){
      return new Date(date).toISOString().substring(0,10);
    }
  }

  onSubmit()
  {

  }

}
```

I am created here"formatDate "function but here is the main problem I am facing.

Here is my Error:-

[image]

how i will resolve this issue.please help.

**Update**

update-book.component.html

```
<div class="update-book">

    <form [formGroup]="updateBookForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title" class="required">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" formControlName="title" placeholder="Book Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="author" class="required">Author</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" formControlName="author" placeholder="Book Author">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description" class="required">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" formControlName="description" placeholder="Book Description">
        </div>
    
        <div class="row">
    
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dateStart">Date Start</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateStart" formControlName="dateStart" placeholder="Date Start">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dateRead">Date Read</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateRead" formControlName="dateRead" placeholder="Date Read">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rate">Rate</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="5" class="form-control" id="rate" formControlName="rate" placeholder="Rate">
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" [routerLink]="['/books']" >CANCEL</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

book.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Book } from '../interfaces/book'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {

  readonly baseURL ="http://localhost:59750/api/Books"


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getAllBooks()
  {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.baseURL+"/GetBooks");
  }

  addBook(book: Book){
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL+"/AddBook/", book);
  }

  getBookById(id:number)
  {
        return this.http.get<Book>(this.baseURL+"/SingleBook/"+id);
  }

  upDateBook(book:Book){
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL+"/UpdateBook/"+book.id,book);
  }

  

}
```

**Update**

book.ts

```
export  interface Book
{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    author: string;
    rate?: number;
    dateStart?: Date;
    dateRead? : Date;
}
```

Comment: Please also post your HTML code and the JSON data being returned.

Comment: You need to add check for possible undefined value. Add in your `formatDate()` method the `else` condition and return a default value if `date = undefined`.

Comment: I think your `book` object is not typed and TypeScript cant recognize the `dateStart` property  as `Date` type.

Comment: @E.Maggini I updated my post.please check

Comment: @DmitryS. please clarify

Comment: just replace `book:any` to `book:Book`

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information to your post by using the [edit] functionality. But please don't pollute your post with `EDIT:` or `UPDATE:` sections. [For future readers, posts need to be standalone, without any history. These sites are not forums, but intend to be libraries of canonical, high-quality, questions and answers. Future readers are not helped by seeing all kind of history.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262)

Comment: @ShayD Not working,same output.

Comment: Does your `Book.dateStart` property is of type Date?

Comment: Can you please add the typings of the `Book` class

Comment: also changing your data subscription from `subscribe(data=>{` to `subscribe((data:Book)=>{` is a better practice that can help you here

Comment: @Batajus i updated my question.please check..

Comment: @ShayD Book.dateStrat is property of ```Book``` class

Comment: I know. I just say that working with typed objects is cleaner

Comment: Just for testing, Does changing `formatDate(date: Date)` to `formatDate(date:Date | undefined)` is working?

Comment: @ShayD same issue.not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So regarding to your question and updates. Your problem is that `dateStart` is an optional property on you `Book` class. That's why you got the error message

> Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

because this property can be undefined by design.

To change this you have two options in my opinion.

1. Make the property `dateStart` to a "normal" property, so the compiler knows that the property is set, by removing the `?`.
2. You can try to cast the property to a `Date`

   ```
   dateStart:[this.formatDate(data.dateStart as Date)],
   ```

This should also prevent the error message, but you need to take care of a potential undefined value in you  `formatDate` function

Comment: this line error gone ``` dateStart:[this.formatDate(data.dateStart)],```   but still found error my formatData() fuction same as my post.

Comment: Error is: ```  error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.

33   formatDate(date : Date){
     ~~~~~~~~~~ ```

Comment: @Batajus I've just realized that the `?` means optional and not nullable. can you explain a bit more? what is actually the different?

Comment: Actually i don't know deeply which you question me.

Comment: @Linkon , (sorry. I have added the name in my last comment just to be clear)  you should now add to your `if` statement the `else` statement and return the value you wish. you probably added the return type to your function `formatDate(date: Date):Date{`

Comment: @Thank you..problem solved. now i understand. :)

Comment: @ShayD what exactly shall I explain more detailed?

Comment: @Batajus Thanks. I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220225/5107490