# Visual Studio Code reports error in Typescript code when null is assigned to a typed variable

Tags: typescript, nullable

I have the following interface:

```
interface CompositeNodeInterface {
  name: string;
  definer: any;
  parent: CompositeNodeInterface;
  children: [CompositeNodeInterface];

  addChild(definer: any): CompositeNodeInterface
}
```

As you can see, attribute `parent` is typed as an object that recursively implements the same interface, and attribute `children` is typed as an array of objects that equally implement recursively the same interface.

I have the following class that implements `CompositeNodeInterface`:

```
export default class CompositeNode implements CompositeNodeInterface {
  name: string;
  definer: any;
  parent: CompositeNode;
  children: [CompositeNode];

  constructor(definer: any) {
    switch(definer.constructor.name) {
      case 'Object':
        if ('name' in definer) {
          this.name = definer.name;
        } else {
          this.name = String(Object.values(definer)[0]);
        }

        break;
      default:
        this.name = definer.toString();
    }

    this.definer = definer;
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];
  }

  acceptVisit(visitor: VisitorInterface) {
    return visitor.visit(this)
  }
}
```

The problem is that when attribute `parent` is set to `null`, VSC reports the following error: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CompositeNode'`, and when attribute `children` is set to `[]`, VSC reports `Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[CompositeNode]'`.

[image]

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220114/how-to-declare-a-type-as-nullable-in-typescript) that all attributes are nullable, so I would expect these operations to be valid.

Comment: `I read here that all attributes are nullable, so I would expect these operations to be valid.` This was 8!! Years ago. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7140 And also, your array should be `CompositeNode[]` which is an array of `CompositeNode`s,  not `[CompositeNode]` which is an array with exactly one `CompositeNode` as element.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks a lot, I haven't noticed about that fact. Your link gave the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you no longer can assign null or undefined values to every field since: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7140

you need to explicitly set the value to nullable, possibly using of a union type, such as `CompositeNode | null`, or additionally you could make parent optional