# Why is the type error displayed different in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I was making some TypeScript code for studying at TypeScript Playground.
But, Errors are sometimes displayed in variables and values, but I don't know why.
Shouldn't the type error be displayed in the undefined of line 7 and 8 instead of a1 and a2?

```
type Foo = any[][]
type Baz = any[]
type Bar = any;

declare const elAny: Bar;

const a1: Foo = undefined; // error displayed under a1
const a2: Baz = undefined; // error displayed under a2
const a3: Bar = undefined;

const b1: Foo = elAny;
const b2: Baz = elAny;
const b3: Bar = elAny;

const c1: Foo = [1, 2, 3]; // error displayed under 1, 2, 3
const c2: Baz = [1, 2, 3];
const c3: Bar = [1, 2, 3];
```

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbeX6.png)

Here's a [TS Playgound link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBDAdiA2gXVwKFEigCFUAvZNTAo6MgJyoxAG598ATCAYwBtUDaDzjoAzsCgQ+AQUwAuUoPb4R4yagCMi+IhQBXdNwBmAS3QROrKAHobUhgzhNOpsWAEhLUQ9yZbVUQk0ACZFMkoDIwgzCytbewhHZyhXd09vXyS0TUD1NABmcMEqLNjLFTVggCNtWAQqaTk2PJqwpUipWUx2KslqoqUmFCaejj6oHjrdKixNABooEMWCnGs7BycXNw9UL04faKYFpZXWyR52iNmT5ahV3qCLwcYbxbuH-CA)

Comment: [add comment]
I want to know why the place where the type error occurs is different than the cause of the type error!!

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the type `any[]` isn't nullable.

To fix it, you can:

1. Simply do `const a2: Baz = [];` for example, to set the variable as array
2. Mark it a nullable with `any[]|null`
3. Mark the variable as nullable with `var?: type;`, mostly use in type declaration but could not be used in this specific example.

You can find more about nullable type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17220114/10952503).

PS: I didn't tried all options, maybe some require more changes.